# Custom Action to Replace "Delete this site" on Site settings

Tags: 2013, custom-actions

I am trying to remove and replace the "Delete this site" on Site settings page.  Can anyone see what is wrong?

My current code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <HideCustomAction
    Id="HideDeleteWeb"
    GroupId="SiteAdministration"
    HideActionId="DeleteWeb"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
  >
  </HideCustomAction>

  <CustomAction
    Description="Replaces the 'Delete this site'"
    Title="REPLACE"
    Id="{E538E8C7-65DA-454E-AD87-4A603B6CC569}"
    GroupId="SiteAdministration" 
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
    >
  </CustomAction>

</Elements>
```

This gives me the following layout.  "Delete this site" is still visable and "REPLACE" is in the wrong place.

[image]

I followed the instructions on the following site but the post is old: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/575d5228-0ac5-4a1b-a435-da35b9392706/disable-delete-this-site-option?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

The "Delete this site" link is under the "Site Actions" heading. However, on Microsoft's "Default Custom Action Locations and IDs" page there is not a "Site Actions" group: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb802730.aspx
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To hide the standard "Delete this site", try to set the `GroupId` to **`SiteTasks`**: `SiteAdministration` is for SP2007, while in SP2010/2013, the link has moved to the section "Site Actions".
- The same applies for your new custom action.

So, you should have now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <HideCustomAction
    Id="HideDeleteWeb"
    GroupId="SiteTasks"
    HideActionId="DeleteWeb"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
  >
  </HideCustomAction>

  <CustomAction
    Description="Replaces the 'Delete this site'"
    Title="REPLACE"
    Id="{E538E8C7-65DA-454E-AD87-4A603B6CC569}"
    GroupId="SiteTasks" 
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
    >
  </CustomAction>

</Elements>
```

(also, I removed the `xmlns` attribute as I don't think it's needed/correct).

Comment: You are correct on all accounts.  How did you know about the SiteTasks GroupId?  The 2013 page from Microsoft doesn't mention that GroupId, is there a more complete list out there?

Comment: I looked for `DeleteWeb` in the hive. I've shut-down my VM right now, so I can't get the exact path of the file...

Comment: These files are pretty good: \15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\SiteSettings\SiteSettings.xml   and   \15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\AdminLinks\Applications.xml